# Why does the following code not output the corresponding letters correctly?

Tags: python, chr, ord

Why does the following code not output the corresponding letters correctly?

It outputs `number to letter is['\x03', '\x03']`

```
final_numbers = [3, 3]
final_letters = []

for i in range(len(final_numbers)):
    print(i)
    number_to_letter=chr(final_numbers[i])
    final_letters.append(number_to_letter)

print ("number to letter is" + str(final_letters))
```

Comment: What do you expect it to output?

Comment: You probably meant to use `str(final_numbers[i])`, `chr(value)` returns the character whose ASCII code is `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chr(3)` returns the character whose ASCII code is 3 (which is '\x03').
To convert number to string (int-str)
You have to do `str()` not `chr()`

So do like this:

```
final_numbers = [3, 3]
final_letters = []

for i in range(len(final_numbers)):
    print(i)
    number_to_letter=str(final_numbers[i])
    final_letters.append(number_to_letter)

print ("number to letter is" + str(final_letters))
```

Or this if you want to do `chr()` (try to guess what the results are)

```
final_numbers = [115, 116, 97, 99, 107, 32, 111, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
final_letters = []

for i in range(len(final_numbers)):
    print(i)
    number_to_letter=chr(final_numbers[i])
    final_letters.append(number_to_letter)

print ("number to letter is" + str(final_letters))
```

Comment: Ahhh I didn't realise it was in ASCII - I just added 96 to chr instead.

Thanks!!

Comment: @BenjaminMcDowell If it solved the problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it